# How do I get specific pixels of the tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

I have an issue with the Tkinter Canvas, saving it to an image, but more importantly, getting a specific pixel of the Tkinter Canvas. All I need is for that specific X, Y coordinate, I want its color value. By 'color value', any value I can use to draw a pixel with the python imaging library would work.

Here's what I tried to do to make it work:

1. I first tried to use python imaging library's image grabbing class to get the Canvas Image, but that didn't work as expected.
2. I then tried to convert the Tkinter Canvas to an image by with the "eps" file, but that didn't work, and GhostScript didn't work either.
3. Next, I searched to see if there was any way to get the pixel at a certain coordinate on a Tkinter canvas to no avail. That's where I posted this.

Next, here's the code I tried for step 2:

```
    screen = w
    @staticmethod
    def image():
        w.postscript(file=".canvas_script.eps")
        img = Image.open(".canvas_script.eps")
        return img
        # GhostScript Error
```

Expected Result: My expected result is to get the color of any certain point, or at least to get a color of the point that I can convert to another color tuple or value. Then, to put draw that on a python imaging library image.

Actual Result: I found no method on the internet when I researched that solved my question, and no method in the documentation.

If anyone can help me get the color from a specific coordinate of the Tkinter Canvas, say (0, 0), please  do. Thanks!

Comment: A Tkinter Canvas *isn't made of pixels* - it's composed of drawing objects, the only time pixels come into play is when those objects are being rendered to the screen.  Exporting to .eps, then loading that image, ought to have worked (and I can't think of any more straightforward way to get the pixel colors you want) - perhaps if you showed the actual error that resulted, rather than uselessly saying "it didn't work", we could help you with that.

Comment: My error was ```OSError: Unable to locate Ghostscript on paths```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I get specific pixels of the tkinter canvas?

You can't. The canvas isn't a pixel oriented widget. The best you can do is use some other library to create a screenshot of the canvas, and then use the image to give you the values that you want.

Comment: I have an idea for a work-around for that. Since my only canvas objects would be images, I would get the image at that coordinate, subtract the minimum x and y from my target x and y, and then get that coordinate of the image.

Comment: @Corman: so, your real question isn't about getting a pixel value of a canvas, but rather how to get a pixel value from an image? Perhaps you should clarify what you're asking in the question so that we know your goal is to get a color from an image.

Comment: Bryan Oakley, I want to get the pixel values from the canvas, and since my only canvas objects are images, I thought I could manipulate the images for some of the values to get the pixel values of the image, since the pixel values of those images would be equal to the pixel values of the canvas in a way.

Comment: @Corman: again: getting pixels values from images is easy. If that's what your ultimate goal is, that should be in your question.

Comment: I never said it was my ultimate goal. My ultimate goal is getting the pixel value from the canvas, and I could use the images to help with that, by getting getting the image at the coordinate, subtracting the input X and Y by the image's min X and min Y, and then getting that pixel of the image, to get that pixel of the canvas.